# How to join Controls with StringBuilder?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a this form created in code behind from SQL Table:

```
  Dim holder As PlaceHolder = CType(FV.FindControl("plControl"), PlaceHolder)
  Dim html As New StringBuilder()

  html.Append("<table>")

  For Each Row As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

     html.Append("<tr style='border: 1px solid black; height:30px;'>")
     html.Append("<td style='padding-right:40px; width:400px; text-align:right; background-color:lightgray;border: 1px solid black;'><b>")
     html.Append(Row(columnName:="Name"))
     html.Append("</b></td>")
     html.Append("<td style='width:300px; text-align:center; background-color:lightgray;border: 1px solid black;'>")
     html.Append("</td>")

     html.Append("<td style='width:300px; text-align:center; background-color:lightgray;border: 1px solid black;'>")
     html.Append("</td>")

     html.Append("</tr>")

  Next

  html.Append("</table>")

  holder.Controls.Add(New Literal() With { _
                   .Text = html.ToString() _
                 })
```

Now in this table I want to add and Controls but every Control added in StringBuilder will be recognized as a HTML text.

I was using this in the loop:

```
  Dim btn As New Button
  btn.Text = "Click me.."
  AddHandler btn.Click, AddressOf MyButton_Click
  MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(btn)
```

But this Control will be added on the top of my table. I just want to know is there any way to add in this table Controls?

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing two different methods of adding controls. For the table, you're building an HTML string, then adding it to the page. For the button, you're creating a Button object and adding that to the page before you add the table. You have to use one method or the other (use objects or HTML strings for everything).

Since you have an event handler for the button, it may be easier to build the table with the [Table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.table(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

There's an example of doing that here: http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/03/17/dynamically-adding-textbox-control-to-aspnet-table.aspx

Then you can add your button to the proper TableCell.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an asp.net Table, you cannot mix html as a string and Controls.

```
'create an asp.net table
Dim table As Table = New Table

'let's add some cells
Dim i As Integer = 0
Do While (i < 5)

    'create a new control for in the table
    Dim linkButton As LinkButton = New LinkButton
    linkButton.ID = ("CellLinkButton_" + i.ToString)
    linkButton.Text = ("LinkButton " + i.ToString)

    'create a new table row
    Dim row As TableRow = New TableRow

    'create 2 new cells, 1 with text and 1 with the linkbutton control
    Dim tableCell As TableCell = New TableCell
    tableCell.Text = ("Cell " + i.ToString)
    row.Cells.Add(tableCell)

    tableCell = New TableCell
    tableCell.Controls.Add(linkButton)
    row.Cells.Add(tableCell)

    'add the new row to the table
    table.Rows.Add(row)

    i = (i + 1)
Loop

'add the table to the placeholder
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(table)
```